# ¿como obtengo una lista dentro de una objeto con thymeleaf sprint data jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf, spring-data

//este es mi entidad
utilizo lombok para el getter and setter y constructores
tengo una lista DetEmpleaUniOrg donde ocurrre mi problema

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name="EMPLEADO")
public class Empleado {
//empleado
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EMPLEADO_SEQ" )
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "EMPLEADO_SEQ", allocationSize = 1,name = "EMPLEADO_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    
    private Integer idJefe;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "personal_id")
    Personal personal;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "empleado")
    List<DetEmpleaUniOrg> DetEmpleaUniOrg;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "institucion_id")
    Institucion institucion;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "especialidad_id")
    Especialidad especialidad;
    
    private String fechaIngreso;
    private String fechaCese;
    
    private String puesto;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "grupoOcupacional_id")
    GrupoOcupacional grupoOcupacional;
    
    private Double remuneracion;
    private String numContrato;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "banco_id")
    Banco banco;
    
    private String numCuenta;
    private String cci;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "penciones_id")
    Penciones penciones;
    
    private Integer activo;
        
}
```

//este es mi controllador
en mi post llamo a mi objeto empleado y luego le paso el activo en 1 para añadir

```
@PostMapping("/guarda")
       public String guardaEmpleado(@ModelAttribute Empleado empleado) {
        empleado.setActivo(1);
        empleadoServiceImpl.guardar(empleado);
        return "redirect:/grado/lista/";
    }
```

//y este es mi html

en mi html lo que hago es utilizar el selecticker de boostrap 4 y thymleaf para recuperar la lista de mi detalle que es par de mi objeto entidad , pero no se como hacer para recuperar esta lista, me trae los id de unidades organicas en null.

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="detEmpleaUniOrg" 
th:name="DetEmpleaUniOrg" >
     <option th:each="det: ${listaOficina}" th:value="${{det.id}}" th:text="${det.nombre}">
</select>
```

este es mi mensaje de error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "pe.gob.acffaa.rrhh.model.DetEmpleaUniOrg.setEmpleado(pe.gob.acffaa.rrhh.model.Empleado)" because "item" is null
    at pe.gob.acffaa.rrhh.service.impl.EmpleadoServiceImpl.guardar(EmpleadoServiceImpl.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at pe.gob.acffaa.rrhh.service.impl.EmpleadoServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ab9ee0a4.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
```

Comment: Coloca el código de la función empleadoServiceImpl.guardar. En principio tiene un problema allí como indica la excepción, intentas acceder a un propiedad de algo llamado item cuando eso está nulo.

Answer (score 0):

usualmente no uso thymeleaf, pero considero que deberías primero buscar a tu empleado, por ejemplo:

```
@PostMapping("/guarda")
       public String guardaEmpleado(@ModelAttribute Empleado empleado) {
       Empleado empleadoEditar = empleadoServiceImpl.buscarPorId(empleado.getId());
       empleadoEditar.setActivo(1);
       empleadoServiceImpl.guardar(empleadoEditar);
       return "redirect:/grado/lista/";
    }
```

Lo que entiendo de tu error es que no encuentra el empleado que quieres editar, entonces por eso primero los buscas con tu método de buscarPorId ó findById ó bien no pasar el objeto empleado directemente  si no su id para buscarlo desde los métodos ya mencionados.